# What are readily usable metal tools to use for sword-like sounds?

Tags: audio-recording, tools

I'm interested in recording a variety of metallic striking sounds, but ones that don't seem to come easy are sword-like sounds for sharp objects. So far I have a machete, and I figure I should be using something like an oversized metal/nail file with a bit of roughness to rub it against, but I don't know what the proper term for such a tool is so I can't look it up to buy it.

Comment: There IS a tool called a file. Is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: I mean I own files for wearing away metal, but none of those exactly quality as they are less than a foot in lenth. I'm looking for an over-sized cylindrical file, I've never seen a tool like that in any store before, so I don't know what it's called.

Comment: ah, a cylindrical one I have not seen. Mine is 1.5 feet long, two inches wide, and a half inch thick. It was just called a file at home depot when i got it. But that was quite some time ago.

Comment: Maybe look for just an all-thread? They come in varying lengths, and the thread would be a similar sound to the file

Comment: I think an all-thread is too rough or the ridges are too large and regular, I'm looking for something that resembles a file or maybe coarse sandpaper.